# How do I change a column type on Windows Azure on Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, azure, web

I'm trying to update a table on Windows Azure but I don't know how.

This is my table. I need to update `detallePeriodo` from `nvarchar(2)` to `nvarchar(4)`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CLIENTE_LIDER]
(
    [Cedula]              NVARCHAR (12)  NOT NULL,
    [Nombre]              NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
    [TelCelular]          NVARCHAR (9)   NULL,
    [TelCasa]             NVARCHAR (9)   NULL,
    [Direccion]           NVARCHAR (200) NULL,
    [Distrito]            INT            NULL,
    [Periosidad]          INT            NULL,
    [DetallePeriodo]      NVARCHAR (2)   NULL,
    [Monto_Total]         FLOAT (53)     DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [Monto_Actual]        FLOAT (53)     DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [Cuota]               FLOAT (53)     DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [Codigo]              VARCHAR (12)   NULL,
    [Ruta]                INT            NULL,
    [FechaIngresoSistema] DATE           NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Cedula] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([Distrito]) REFERENCES [dbo].[DISTRITOS] ([codigo]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_CLIENTE_LIDER_0] FOREIGN KEY ([Ruta]) REFERENCES [dbo].[RUTA] ([Codigo])
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms190273(v=sql.120).aspx), which applies to both SQL Server and the Azure SQL Database, it appears you just need a fairly standard `ALTER` statement.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.CLIENTE_LIDER ALTER COLUMN DetallePeriodo NVARCHAR(4);
```

Comment: It works sorry im on my first days on job and im soo scare to screw the database hahaha thanks for all :D